# Is the sentence ‘Without so much as a call or a letter – he showed up‘ written with acceptable punctuation?

Tags: orthography, dashes, style-manuals, emphasis

Please consider:

1. Without so much as a call or a letter – he showed up.

Is sentence (1) above not only grammatical in syntax and morphology, but
also acceptably punctuated according to guidelines for standard written
English worldwide?

I know that dashes can be used to emphasize parenthetical information, but
I feel as though the parenthetical element typically comes either within an
enclosing set of dashes or else after a single dash, not before one. After
all, dashes typically draw attention to and emphasize what comes after (or
within).

Therefore, does placing a dash *after* a parenthetical element still draw
attention to that parenthetical element, or does it draw attention to the
independent clause which follows it?

Is it even good style to use a dash in a sentence with a parenthetical
element in order to emphasize the independent clause rather than the
parenthetical one?

Here’s an example of what I’m wondering about:

2. He showed up – without so much as a call or a letter.

Here the emphasis is on *without so much...* in sentence (2) above, isn’t it?

And wouldn’t that be different from this?

3. Without so much as a call or a letter – he showed up.

Because here in sentence (3) the emphasis is on *...he showed up*, isn’t it?

But is this stylistically appropriate for sentences with this grammar?

Comment: Unable to understand the need for a parenthetical usage here.

Comment: I don't think I've come across a rule / recommendation forbidding this, but I'd agree that placing the independent clause first is usual. Certainly you can't use sentence fragments ('Without so much as a call or a letter. He showed up.') fragment-first without suitable prior context. But if you use a comma as separator, the construction would raise no eyebrows.

Comment: I don't think much of the dash there. Obviously it would look silly with a straightforward  single-word adverb: ***Soon - he showed up***, and I can't see why it should become more acceptable just because the adverbial element contains more than one word. ***Wearing his hat tipped at a jaunty angle - he showed up***. I don't think so. The longer the adverbial element, the more justification there is for setting it off with a ***comma*** (as an aid to parsing, for the reader). But never a dash, imho.

Comment: I'd say the way you presented it is fine.  Others would use a different punctuation, but that's a personal choice.  Revering the order of the phrases would shift the emphasis in a way that is probably not desired.

Comment: Oops -- I meant "Reversing".

Comment: Without some context as to why this was said, and what was meant by it, answers will be opinions.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a dash, a comma will suffice. The sentence, with the introductory phrase, is strong enough without the dash. See Harbrace College Handbook: With 1998 MLA Style Manual Updates, 13th Revised Edition (HODGES HARBRACE HANDBOOK)
by John C. Hodges, Winifred Bryan Horner, et al. | Jan 1, 1998

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is ***not*** an answer. A dash—if it is allowed here—makes for a stronger sentence.

Comment: Welcome to our site, Mary! Good to have you here. Please consider taking our site [tour] to familiarize yourself with how our question-and-answer model works.  As our Community robot has recommended in its comment to you above, we very much prefer longer, more detailed answers, ones optimally including citations from reputable sources and which always provide an explanation of ***why*** the answer you have given should be considered correct by others.

Answer (score 0):

Either option is fine. The second sentence where 'he showed up' is at the end of the sentence adds emphasis to the suddeness with which he appeared. It's really only a question of sylistic preference by the writer here.

Comment: 'Answers' require a degree of support (here, from grammars and/or examples from respected authors) that 'comments' don't (though accuracy in 'comments' is also important).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132735/discussion-on-answer-by-mozibur-ullah-without-so-much-as-a-call-or-a-letter--h).